Build Katran LoadBalancer
I'm trying to build and run Katran on Ubuntu, following the instructions in the official documentation here. The build completes successfully without any errors. However, I’m unsure of the next steps: how do I actually run Katran and start using it?

This one https://github.com/facebookincubator/katran ? According to the very first paragraph it's not a program that you can use, but a library that you can include and use when you develop your own applications.

Hi @GeraldSchneider, thanks for your response! Could you provide more details on using Katran as a Layer 4 load balancer? I have a setup with two backend web servers and a front server, and I'd like to use Katran on the front server to handle TCP and UDP traffic, forwarding it to the backend servers (with UDP for HTTP/3 requests). How can I configure Katran to achieve this?
